# GDB instruction level single step over doesn't work with stripped elf?

Tags: gdb

I'm debugging a stripped elf with gdb.When I use "ni" to step over a function,GDB still step into the function.Then,how to instruction level single step over?

```
(gdb) x/5i $pc
0x2495: call   0xd900
0x249a: mov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax
0x249d: call   0x300b3 <dyld_stub_chdir>
0x24a2: mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc]
0x24a5: mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x4],eax
(gdb) ni
0x0000d900 in ?? ()
(gdb)
```